# To check whether 0 is eigenvalue of the given matrix

Tags: matrices

consider the matrix
 $$
\begin{bmatrix}
1+x^2&7&11\\
3x&2x&4\\
8x&17&13\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ ; $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Then

1.A(x) has eigenvalue 0 for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$

2.0 is not eigenvalue of A(x) for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$

3.A(x) has eigenvalue 0 for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

4.A(x) is invertible for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$

The characteristic equation for given matrix is $26x^3-182x^2+538x-68=0$

The determinant of principle minor

\begin{vmatrix}
1+x^2&7\\
3x&2x
\end{vmatrix}is = $2x^3-19x$ which is 0 if x=0.

so can i say 0 is eigenvalue for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Hint: there is an eigenvalue $0$ iff the homogeneous linear system with coefficient matrix above have a non-zero solution, which shall occur iff the determinant is zero.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't the characteristic equation of this matrix be in terms of the variable (say $\lambda$) which represents the eigenvalues? Perhaps what you have computed is the determinant. So if that is the determinant then as you can see it is a cubic equation so must have a real root and for that $x$ the determinant will be $0$, implying that the matrix will have a zero eigenvalue for at least one real $x$.

Furthermore, the determinant is not $0$ for all $x$. This means choice number (3) cannot be true.

Answer (score 0):

Zero is an eigenvalue $\iff$ determinant is zero $\iff$ the matrix isn't invertible.

You can see that the determinant will be a polynomial on $x$ of degree $3$, since third degree terms only come from $(1+x^2) \times (2x*13 - 4*17) = 26x^3\dots$.
I realize that this is what you have calculated. This isn't the characteristic equation. This is the determinant (that just happens to depend on $x$ since the entries of the matrix depend on $x$).

A third degree polynomial must have a real zero. On the other hand, it isn't identically zero. So the option 1. is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the reasoning is not correct.

Let $x=0$, the matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 7 & 11 \\ 0 & 0  & 4 \\ 0 & 17 & 13\end{bmatrix}$$

Even though the first $2$ by $2$ submatrix is singular, the whole matrix is not singular, the determinant of this $1 ( 0(13)-4(17)) \neq 0$

Option $3$ is not true.

If option $4$ is true, then option $1$ is true.

\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix} 1+x^2 & 7 & 11 \\ 3x & 2x & 4 \\ 8x & 17 & 13 \end{vmatrix}&=\begin{vmatrix} 1+x^2 & -4 & 11 \\ 3x & 2x-4 & 4 \\ 8x & -4 & 13 \end{vmatrix}\\
&=2\begin{vmatrix} 1+x^2 & -2 & 11 \\ 3x & x-2 & 4 \\ 8x & -2 & 13 \end{vmatrix}\\&=
2\begin{vmatrix} 1+x^2-8x & 0 & -2 \\ -5x & x & -9 \\ 8x & -2 & 13 \end{vmatrix}\\&=
2 ((1+x^2-8x)(13x-18)-2(10x-8x^2))\end{align}

which is a cubic equation. hence the range of determinant takes any real value including $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic equation is
$$\lambda ^3+\lambda ^2 \left(-x^2-2 x-14\right)+\lambda  \left(2 x^3+13 x^2-81 x-55\right)-26 x^3+244 x^2-538 x+68=0$$
if we plug $\lambda=0$ we get $-26 x^3+244 x^2-538 x+68=0$ which has three real roots, thus (1) is true and (2) and (3) false.

Matrix is invertible when no eigenvalue is zero, therefore (4) is false because we have stated that  $-26 x^3+244 x^2-538 x+68=-\det A=0$ for three values of $x\in \mathbb{R}$,

$x_1\approx 0.134478,\;x_2\approx 3.23119, \;x_3\approx 6.01895$

hope this helps